# Apply not playing nicely with table

Tags: r

I'm getting two different structures returned when I use apply with the table function.

Here's some sample data

```
d1 <- data.frame(q1 = c(1,2,3), q2 = c(3,2,1))
d2 <- data.frame(q1 = c(1,2,3), q2 = c(3,2,2))

d1 <- data.frame(lapply(d1, factor, ordered=TRUE, 
                        levels=c(1,2,3), 
                        labels=c("Dissatisfied",
                                 "Neutral",
                                 "Satisfied"
                        )))

d2 <- data.frame(lapply(d2, factor, ordered=TRUE, 
                        levels=c(1,2,3), 
                        labels=c("Dissatisfied",
                                 "Neutral",
                                 "Satisfied"
                        )))
```

Now if I run the apply function

```
apply_1 <- apply(d1,2,table)
apply_2 <- apply(d2,2,table)
```

apply_1 is a nice table (this is the output I'm expecting)

```
str(apply_1)
```

but apply_2 is a list, not what I wanted or expected

```
str(apply_2)
```

I'm guessing this is because one of the factors is not present as a value in column 2 of d2

But running the table command on each column separately gives what I want

```
table(d2[ , 1])
table(d2[ , 2])
```

Do I need to change the apply function into a loop and bind all the outputs together or is there a way I can make apply play nicely with the table function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` coerces `d1/2` to a `matrix` before applying a function, which drops your `factor` coding. Which means your `table` results are different lengths for `d2`, resulting in a `list` being returned.

Instead, try:

```
sapply(d1,table)

#             q1 q2
#Dissatisfied  1  1
#Neutral       1  1
#Satisfied     1  1

sapply(d2,table)

#             q1 q2
#Dissatisfied  1  0
#Neutral       1  2
#Satisfied     1  1
```